# iOS Calendar showing year as 2559 BE

Tags: ios, calendar

My iPhone 5's Calendar shows the year as 2559 BE and I'm unable to change that to the current year.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your phone doesn't actually have the wrong year. It looks like your phone is set to use a Buddhist calendar for some reason. To change it to Gregorian:

Go to Settings > Language & Region > Calendar > Gregorian.